# Objective-C Redefine Class

Tags: objective-c, class, reflection, constants

I have some Code that I'd like to share between an iOS and an OSX project. Unfortunately, some classes, while functionally relatively similar (and having greatly overlapping interface definitions), are parts of different hierarchies and frameworks, and have different names. UIKit/AppKit classes are a prime example.

One solution would be to use preprocessor directives, but that creates a lot of duplicate code:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
  - (UIImage *)getImage; //have to create an implementation for each
#else
  - (NSImage *)getImage; //have to create an implementation for each
#endif;
```

I had thought about using reflection. In Objective-C, it's possible to dynamically get a Class object with the use of `NSClassFromString(@"name")`. This is very nice, but if used often, creates ugly code. It also can't be used in a header file, because it's not constant, so this does not work:

```
//defined once per project
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
  Class NUImage = NSClassFromString(@"UIImage");
#else
  Class NUImage = NSClassFromString(@"NSImage");
#endif;

//usage
- (NUImage *)getImage; //does not compile
```

**I want to be able to define (ideally at compile time) a Class Synonym, so that it can be used transparently in place of the specific implementation class. Is this possible? In essence, I want to avoid having to write a wrapper class** (which would either just forward messages to the concrete implementation, thus be easy to write but take away code completion and checking, or be a lot of boilerplate code just to duplicate the interface of the class(es) it's wrapping).

Is it possible to store the Class as a constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try something like:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
typedef UIImage NUIImage; // NUIImage is an alias for UIImage
#else
typedef NSImage NUIImage; // NUIImage is an alias for NSImage
#endif
```

And then use NUIImage everywhere you would have used either NSImage or UIImage. Typedef is inherited from C, so it's a compile cost only with no impact upon the runtime (so, e.g. `NSClassFromString(@"NUIImage")` would return `nil` all other thing being equal). It causes the compiler to consider the one thing to be an alias of the other. If you were adopting strict C conventions you'd probably call it `NUIImage_t`.

---

The following is an edited version of my original answer, based on an original, mistaken reading that the question hinged on using a specific class that may or may not exist, with that fact not known until runtime. It's accurate for that sort of situation, but not especially relevant:

You don't need to find a solution that works in method definitions or in any of the other definitions normally used in a header file; you can just use the class name there. In Objective-C you always refer to objects by pointer and all pointers look the same to the hardware. The use of typed pointers in source code is therefore a bit of a fiction for the benefit of the programmer (including indirectly via relevant compiler warnings) with no effect on the generated binary.

As long as a definition like the following compiles, it doesn't matter whether neither `SomeClass` nor `SomeOtherClass` are available at runtime:

```
- (SomeClass *)someMethod:(SomeOtherClass *)argument;
```

You won't get an exception just for having declared the method.

The only place you really need to use `NSClassFromString` is wherever you make an initial branch on whether or not a type of object is defined. For example, you can write the following class:

```
@interface SomeClassThatUsesSomeOtherClass

- (id)init;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) SomeOtherClass *otherClassInstance;

- (void)doSomeTask;
- (SomeOtherClassResult *)doSomeOtherTask;

@end

/* elsewhere */

@implementation SomeClassThatUsesSomeOtherClass

@synthesize otherClassInstance;

- (id)init
{
    // blah blah blah, standard init stuff here

    // switch is made implicitly here, because if we get nil back
    // then we'll end up with nil in 'otherClassInstance' — we're
    // considering the class not existing to be equivalent to any
    // other issue that might cause an instance not to be created
    otherClassInstance = [[NSStringFromClass(@"SomeClass") alloc] init];
    if(!otherClassInstance)
    {
        [self release];
        return nil;
    }

    // blah blah blah, rest of standard init
}

// you'll need a suitable dealloc, too

- (void)doSomeTask
{
    [self.otherClassInstance doAThing];
    [self.otherClassInstance doAnotherThing];
}

- (SomeOtherClassResult *)doSomeOtherTask
{
    return [self.otherClassInstance doAThirdThing];
}

@end
```

And your code is completely safe, automatically working or not working depending on whether the class is available.

Comment: Defining a method like `- (NonexistantClass *)getNC;` results in a parse issue for me, and LLVM won't compile.

Comment: The compiler needs to know what the class is — have you no interface definition for it at all?

Comment: OK, suppose I want a class that I can use in both iOS and OS X, and depending on environment, I need it to work with, say, `NSImage` or `UIImage`. So instead of writing a wrapper class `NUImage`, I had hoped I could just define a constant called NUImage that resolves to the proper Class on each platform (with one `#ifdef` in the constant declaration, and from there on, transparently). I suppose that is not possible. Are you suggesting I declare instead an empty class and "lie" to the compiler that I'm gonna use that one?

Comment: You could use a typedef in that situation. The only annoying thing is that it'd be at compile time, so you'd have to pick UIImage or NSImage based on some flag visible to the preprocessor. If you wanted a runtime solution, I guess you'd write a proxy class that does nothing at all beyond message forwarding.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted to do. Sometimes I miss the trees for the forest (or something). I now have this declaration in my `Constants.h`: `#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    typedef UIImage NUImage;
#else
    typedef NSImage NUImage;
#endif`. This works great, even with code completion etc. If you want to put this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Also, if this method has some unexpected pitfalls or side-effects (or is somehow considered bad practice), feel free to elaborate. Thank you again! :)

Comment: I just rewrote the question to make it clearer what I'm asking. Sorry for not being clear enough in the first place. Forest/trees.

Comment: All done. Other than the potential confusion around it being a purely compile-time thing, so the runtime won't have any record of an 'NUImage', I don't think there are any side effects of using typedef.

Answer (score 2):

You could (this is how I was doing it back then) use the `preprocessor` like this:

```
#define MY_CLASS_NAME @"MyClassName"
```

in separate .h file (which you could include in your .pch file) and then use it like this where you need

```
Class myClassInstance = NSClassFromString(MY_CLASS_NAME);
```

:)

Comment: I've tried that, but it has two problems: It's still not as elegant, and it's still impossible to use in header files or method definitions.

Comment: I am sorry but I couldn't get the part with "impossible to use in head3ers". Are you trying to declare the class with className being a constant? :)

Comment: I have a class that I want to use in both an iOS and an OSX project, and depending on the platform, certain things are represented by different classes (NSImage vs. UIImage, for instance). I'd like to be able to reuse most of my code. As a workaround, I'm using `#ifdef` preprocessor directives, but that doesn't exactly make the code more beautiful. And I'm also interested in this because it seems interesting :)

Comment: I think that you are using the correct approach already, which is to use `#ifdef` preprocessor directives. It may not be nice but code that handles two distict frameworks will never look nice. I think the best you can hope for is to minimize the number of files where all these directives occur. Besides, how would you determine MY_CLASS_NAME without using directives?

Comment: @aLevel: I had hoped to be able to limit the use of the directive to just my Constants file, and use the pseudoclass (or proxy, or Class object instance, or whatever one may to call it) transparently in all other classes.